# How can I prove or refute this $(A\cup B)\setminus C = (A \setminus C) \cup B \iff B \cap C = \varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone please tell me what is the easiest way to Prove or Refute this problem?

$$(A\cup B)\setminus C = (A \setminus C) \cup B  \space\space\space\space\space iff \space\space\space\space\space B \cap C = \varnothing$$

Comment: Try drawing some Venn diagrams to get some intuition for the problem.  When writing the formal proof, if the statement is true, then it should be a straight set-equality argument: that is, $(A\cup B)\setminus C\subset (A\setminus C)\cup B$ and $(A\cup B)\setminus C\supset (A\setminus C)\cup B$.  If it is false, then come up with some specific $A,B,C$ that provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

If $B\cap C\ne\emptyset$, let $x\in B\cap C$. Then $x\in A\cup B$, and $x\not\in (A \cup B)\setminus C$ as the removal of $C$ removes $x$.

On the other hand, $x\not\in A\setminus C$, but is re-introduced in $(A\setminus C)\cup B$.

If $B\cap C=\emptyset$, then subtracting $C$ from either $A$ or $A\cup B$ only removes (if any) elements of $A$, and leaves $B$ intact.

Or, $(A\cup B)\setminus C=(A\setminus C)\cup(B\setminus C)=(A\setminus C)\cup B$.